# Gradle: use file contents as property value

Tags: gradle

Assume I have a description in a file and I want to use the file contents for setting a property in Gradle. What I'm currently doing is something like that

```
String myChangeNotes = file('resources/META-INF/change-notes.html').text
String myDescription = file('resources/META-INF/description.html').text

patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes = myChangeNotes
    pluginDescription = myDescription
}
```

It works, but it does not reload the file when it changes. I guess I have to make a task that has as input the two HTML files so that Gradle knows when they change, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

How would I do it so that the `changeNotes` and `pluginDescription` properties of `patchPluginXml` are reloaded each time the files change on disk?

Comment: @Vampire Oh gosh, you are of course correct. The problem was (attention!) my midnight-commander that I used to check the compiled plugin. It seems mc caches stuff although I reloaded the view and opened the zip file again it still showed me the old contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a task that has the contents of the files as input. As you read the files in the configuration phase, they are always read freshly when you start your build. The `changeNotes` and `pluginDescription` fields of the `patchPluginXml` task (if we talk about the `gradle-intellij` plugin) are defined as inputs, so if their value changes, the task will be re-run. So everything seems to be set up correctly.